# php get value one by one from array

Tags: php

how can i get value every call get next value in array?
i want run crone mysitedotcom/getvalue.php. every run i need get value from array one by one. i dont want get random or any shuffle value .. i need every refresh get next value

```
  $array = [
  'one' =>   11,
  'two'   =>   22,
  'three'   =>   33
   ];
  $val = i need single value one by order
```

i want output like this

```
 first output = 11
 after refresh = 22
 after refresh = 33
 after refresh = 11
 after refresh = 22
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you want to get the next value with each page request? That's quite a big subject to answer here, but you can start by researching PHP Sessions. That's the standard way to preserve status across page requests.

Comment: yes u r right .. i never see any Question and answer like this .. i already searched bro.. i know its simple code.. but my mind nor work for this simple code

Comment: Here's a page to get you started: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php. This shows you how to store a value, and then check/change it again every time a page is called.

Comment: You can use sessions to store the current index number and when the page refreshes you can get the index from the session and call the array with value to print. If the session value is blank then call the 1st value and store the next index or value in the session. On next refresh it will again check for session, since new value is been set in session you can use that and update the session value with next index and so on..

Comment: how can start over again after last index? pls example code..

Comment: Bear in mind that cron jobs will likely not share a session between requests without some tweaking.  You might want a 'queue' instead, or you could perhaps use something like Curl with cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution with sessions:

```
  session_start();

  if(!isset($_SESSION['key'])){
    $_SESSION['key'] = 'one';
  }

  $a = [
    'one' => 11,
    'two' => 22,
    'three' => 33
  ];

  echo $a[$_SESSION['key']];

  $keys = array_keys($a);
  $_SESSION['key'] = $keys[array_search($_SESSION['key'], $keys) + 1];
```

Comment: thank you ur code working fine.. but how can i use my array with key? its not work with my example array.. pls help

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

- Store a key variable and increment it each time (don't forget to reset when reaching array length).
- Create a copy array where you take the first entry then delete it. If array is empty, copy the original array again.

Either one or the other, why would you do that ?

Edit: with both solution you have to save it in a database or session, wether you use the key or the array.

Comment: how and after finish all key how can start again??

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question. The important bit is how to "Remember" what value the client received last time it visited the page.

Comment: Set your key to 0 again it reaches count($array) with an if condition. Also don't foget that count() returns the number of entry and the array index starts at 0, so it will be `$key++; if (count($array) <= $key) $key = 0;` (put it after reading)